# Do stacks have indexes?

Tags: stack

Yeah, so one of my friends said we can use indexes to traverse a stack, but I think he's wrong. Basically, I have a homework in which I had to write an algorithm using an array. I had to use two for loops to do it, so I was wondering how to do something like this with a stack:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        x = A[i]+A[j]
    }
}
```

There is no way right? And I have to use pop() and push() only to do whatever I need to do, right? Because I used an array and stack concurrently, but one of my friends told me I can't do that. I know we can implement a stack using an array, but the stack ADT doesn't have indexes (although they just said stack and not stack ADT).

Comment: you are overwriting x each time, so what is the point of the loop?  Perhaps post another question about your loop question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> said we can use indexes to traverse a stack, but I think he's wrong.

You're right, he's wrong.

> There is no way [to do two nested loops] right?

You can access element at `index` if you have enough space for a temporary stack: pop to the index while storing the popped values onto a temp stack, remember the value, and then push the values back:

```
int GetAt(Stack s, int index) {
    Stack temp;
    while (temp.size() != index) {
        temp.push(s.pop());
    }
    int res = temp.top();
    while (!temp.empty()) {
        s.push(temp.pop());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Yes, that's very, very slow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a pure stack abstraction would not have indices. But pure abstractions rarely exist outside of Comp Sci classrooms and Haskell User's Groups, and most stack implementations can admit to something like this, because indeed, they are usually implemented using an array. At the end of the day, you don't get a prize for how "pure" something is, but rather for getting the job done. I can certainly imagine a situation in which you build up a stack, and then at some point, you need to process all the elements as given in your loop. Welcome to the real world!

Comment: I am taking an algorithm course, my TA said I should probably use pop() and push(), but I can't think of any way on how to implement something as complex as two for loops. I can use a queue to do a similar thing, but with a stack... That's another story.

Comment: stack and loop are different things, stacks are data structures, loops are flow control.  Stacks cannot loop, loops cannot stack.

Answer (score 1):

"Stack" is an abstract concept, not something that exists in reality. In the real world, they are generally implemented as data in consecutive memory addresses, and so indexing them is certainly possible, depending on the language/library/API you're using. Without a specific language or library, there's really no way to answer a question like yours.

If what you really mean is, is there a way to do the calculation you mention with two data collections that can only be accessed by push/pop, then probably not without an intermediate array. But why would you want to? A stack is, by its very nature, intended to be used for algorithms that only need to access its data in a LIFO way. Why else would you use one?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're all wrong(tm)!  With two stacks ("pure" stacks) you can implement an array, inefficiently.  Suppose stack S1 has 10 items pushed on it, and you want item 5; just pop 4 items off of S1, pushing each on to S2 in turn.  Then pop off one more and that is your item.  Just keep track of the index of the item that is currently in use (on neither stack), and you can always retrieve any of the other items when you need them.

But this idea is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Reverse Polish Notation for how to use stacks for computing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation

Basically push the values, then pop them off and apply a function.

Answer (score 0):

Stack have index. Depending on how you implement stack we can use array or link list to implement stack  in array the indexing is start from left to right from zero.  But  we can do indexing in both ways either from

1. stack top element  to bottom most element
2. bottom most element  to top most element